# How do I know the height of Label in my customCollectionViewLayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I subclassed `UICollectionViewLayout` and implemented all the necessary methods like `PrepareLayout`, `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` , `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect`. Previously the height of `UICollectionViewCell` was kept fixed but now as the requirement changed, I want to resize my cell's height as per label height.
How could I get the label text in my `UICollectionViewLayout` class?

Any type of hint or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this to define `cellWidth` and `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` in the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` extension of VC.

Defined the `cellWidth` according to the dynamic height and width of device.

```
let cellWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 7 - 1
```

and is the function that returns dynamic cellWidth and height accordingly. 
I needed the width and height to be of same dimensions, and I have divided it by 7 in the case that I needed 7 row and 7 columns, you can change it according to your need of cells in a single row.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
}
```

Comment: But I subclassed `UICollectionViewLayout` not `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the width of the label, text and font you can use this NSString method:

```
- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options attributes:(nullable NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)attributes context:(nullable NSStringDrawingContext *)context
```

Parameters to use:

`size` - width should be equal to the width of the label, as height you can put CGFLOAT_MAX.

`options` - just use NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin

`attributes` - a dictionary with key `NSFontAttributeName` and value being the font that you'll use for this label

`context` - you can pass nil here

Return value will be CGRect, out of which you just take height and that will be the height of your label in cell with text in it.